# How do I atomically replace a vector?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

I'm writing a multi-threaded program using C++11. I want to replace a vector atomically, while there may be some other worker threads iterating over the old vector. I don't care about if old workers' work is wasted, but I have to make sure that the replacement is atomic and new workers will get the new vector.

I think I probably need a `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>>>`? However, since `std::shared_ptr` is not trivially copyable, it can't compile. The following code (seems?) works, but it leaks memory:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>

std::atomic<std::vector<int>*> v;

void read(const char* name) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int x : *v) sum += x;
    printf("read(%s) sum = %ld\n", name, sum);
}

void replace() {
    v = new std::vector<int>(100, 2);
}

int main() {
    v = new std::vector<int>(10000000, 1);
    std::thread t1(read, "t1");
    std::thread t2(read, "t2");
    std::thread t3(replace);
    t3.join();
    std::thread t4(read, "t4");
    std::thread t5(read, "t5");
    t1.join();t2.join();t4.join();t5.join();
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at an approach such as [RCU](https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/) where writers can atomically switch pointers to structures via `memory_order_release` while readers safely read via `memory_order_consume`, and only once it's deemed that no new readers can observe the old pointer, the writer is able to reclaim the memory. Of course, other memory reclamation strategies would work, including hazard pointers and reference counting.

Comment: t3 here can replace the vector before t2 enters the read() function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shared_ptr is already thread safe, you don't (and can't) wrap it in `atomic<>`.  Simply copy the shared_ptr in your reader, and in the writer you can `swap` it with a new one once you're done populating the new data.

Comment: @abcdabcd987: Just a tip on "it works!" I don't think your test code in that gist is good enough to tell. I would make them use a few million iterations of `replace` occurring in a loop of its own.

Comment: Umm... The reference counts in the control block are safe, but the actual pointer swap isn't guaranteed to be atomic; if one thread is copying out the pointer at the same time another is swapping it in, there could be issues if the hardware can't guarantee the pointer write is always atomic. There is no `atomic` wrapper for `shared_ptr`, but [there are `atomic` functions for `shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic).You'd want to do `std::atomic_store_explicit(&v, std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(100, 2), std::memory_order_release);` and...

Comment: ... in the `read` function, lead with `auto localv = std::atomic_load_explicit(&v, std::memory_order_acquire);` to get the required safety. Per cppreference: "If multiple threads of execution access the same std::shared_ptr object without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur unless all such access is performed through these functions, which are overloads of the corresponding atomic access functions (std::atomic_load, std::atomic_store, etc.)"

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I think technically you're right.   Thanks for that.  However, I guess it only matters on platforms where pointers are wider than the bus, which means it'll be pretty hard to find a computer where this matters.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: True. But in more complicated code, it also gives you instruction ordering guarantees that protect you from other threading issues, so it's a good idea regardless; on your common x86 systems, it doesn't even cost you anything performance-wise (since x86 has strongly ordered memory semantics, as long as you don't use `seq_cst`, you're not forcing additional memory barriers, just preventing compile time instruction reordering). If performance doesn't suffer, and it blocks a source of extremely subtle bugs, I'd call that worthwhile.